# How to access elements from an ItemCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, itemcollection

I want to access the contents of an `ItemCollection` that contains the items from a `Treeview` (called OOB).

```
if (OOB.Items.Count > 0)
{
    ItemCollection items = OOB.Items;
    foreach (TreeViewItem node in items)
```

The `foreach` throws the runtime error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'.

I can SEE the information in the `ItemCollection` items that I want to access from the debugger:

[image]

How can I access the elements, specifically the Element Name?

Comment: using the var keyword here should fix your issue

Comment: Well, that solves the runtime error, but how do I access the values in node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Items` or `ItemsSource` collection of an ItemsControl contains data items of an arbitrary type, not TreeViewItems (unless you explicitly add them).

The `Items` collection of your TreeView contains XmlElements, which you can directly access like this:

```
foreach (XmlElement node in OOB.Items)
{
    var name = node.Name; // node is an XmlElement
    ...
}
```

---

In case you really need access to the item container, you may use the ItemsControl's `ItemContainerGenerator` like this:

```
var treeViewItem = (TreeViewItem)OOB.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(node);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do  var name = node.Name. The only options I'm given for node are Equals, Get Hash Code, Get Type and ToString(). The other method is legit, but this isn't working if (treeViewItem.Name == "Commander"). Ideas?

Comment: How about `foreach (XmlElement node in OOP.Items)`?

Comment: For "the other method", that was just to show how to get the TreeViewItem container of a data item. Of course that TreeViewItem has no Name property.

Comment: With a bit of modification, I think this is going to work. I would mark this as the answer if I could.

Comment: Well, it seems like foreach (XmlElement node in OOB.Items) is only returning the FIRST OOB.Items whereas ItemCollection items = OOB.Items; returned an array of them all.

Comment: Of course you'll have to iterate *recursively* through the XML tree. An XmlElement may have siblings **and** [child nodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes(v=vs.110).aspx). That's the definition of a tree.